# Forgot BitLock password- can I use dictionary attack?

Tags: bitlocker, dictionary

I know that password has 10 possible words, but I don't know in which order. Can I write a simple bot and try to brute force the password that way? Is there some lockout time on BitLock?

Comment: Welcome to Security Stack Exchange!

Comment: "10 possible words" is not very clear. How long is the password (in words)?

Comment: @Polynomial It seems clear enough. The OP seems to be saying the password is 10 known words in length in an unknown order. Assuming no word is allowed to repeat (all 10 must be used), there are 3,628,800 possible passphrases.

Comment: with some or all of 10 words, we find 10,000,000,000 combinations. that could be brute forced, but it might take a while, but certainly not forever.

Comment: @ells It is difficult to answer your question without knowing whether you have the TPM enabled on you machine. If the TPM is enabled, it would not be practical to bruteforce. The TPM will lockout after a number of failed attempts (varies by TPM manufacturer). Lockout lasts for variable amount of time or until shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a TPM enabled, it contains a part of your key that's really difficult to extract, if I'm not mistaken. You can only bruteforce the part of the key that's derived from your password, which is not enough to decrypt your data.

The TPM will not enable the decryption if it detects that the system it's booting has been tampered with. So, no bruteforce bot.

Without lots of money and efforts, I would say that you'll have to try manually. But take all of this with a grain of salt, as I've never used BitLocker or a TPM, and don't know much about them.

Comment: There is a backup key on BitLocker which can be bruteforced. However given its length and randomness (it's generated by the system - the user can't set a bad password) it's practically impossible.